# Incomplete response string from server in implementing POST-requests

Tags: c++, linux, curl

I’m writing the program sending POST-requests to the server and getting answers from it. (using curl library) (OS Linux, Red Hat Linux 3.2.2.-5). Sometimes I see ,  that response from server contains only second part of the message. ( I print _sResponse  and sometimes I see  full message(more often) and sometimes broken message(only last part of it)).

```
Class CurlSoapHandler
{
……..

static std::string _sResponse;
static std::string GetResponse() {return _sResponse;}


static size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, std::string *buffer)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (buffer != NULL)
    {
        std::string tmp_buffer(ptr, size * count);
        _sResponse = tmp_buffer;
        result = size * count;
    }
    else
{
    std::cout<<"Buffer is not OK!"<<std::endl;
    }    
            return result;
   }

};

void CurlSoapHandler::DoRequest(const std::string& sRequest, std::string& sResponse)
{
    CURL* _CURL;
CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Content-Type:text/xml");
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    _CURL = curl_easy_init();
    if(_CURL)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt( _CURL, CURLOPT_URL, ttp://10.10.10.11:8083/Server/Server.asmx);

        curl_easy_setopt( _CURL, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user@password");
        curl_easy_setopt( _CURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, sRequest.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt( _CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);

        curl_easy_setopt( _CURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

        curl_easy_setopt( _CURL, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlSoapHandler::write_data);
        res = curl_easy_perform(_CURL);
        sResponse = GetResponse(); 
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {   
            std::cerr<<"CURL message: "<<curl_easy_strerror(res)<<std::endl;

        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(_CURL);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Curl initialization problem!"<<std::endl;
    }
  curl_global_cleanup();
  curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);
     }
```

I have no ideas why it occurs. Does someone have ideas? (May be it’s necessary to set some curl options, for example). How can I determine the reason for  it and understand if it’s  problem of my applications or not.  I'd caught traffic using tcpdump utility (I run it on my Virtual Machine (VMWARe)) and saw full message in the dump. So, I think that server sends the correct response. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to accumulate data in your write function. It will be called more than once for the same request.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!But I don't understand how I can implement that in my code.

Comment: Create a request class, in a class have `std::string result` member. Make your write function a method of that class. Each time it's called, do `result += buffer`.

Comment: Thank very much!So, should I call write function twice for one request, right?

Comment: I call it twice now, and it seems to me that problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `_sResponse = tmp_buffer;` by `_sResponse += tmp_buffer;` shoulds work.